# Selectively print from multiline output with awk after single iteration

Tags: awk, amazon-ec2

thanks for taking the time to read!

I'm attempting to direct the output of an Amazon EC2 command through awk in order to obtain information to pass through to other commands.  The issue is that I need to obtain output from multiple lines at multiple points that have multiple matches.  Here's the example:

I issue the following command against ec2:

```
ec2-describe-instances  --filter tag:Name=webserver_name*  --show-empty-fields
```

which outputs:

```
RESERVATION r-RESERVATION_ID_1  OWNER_ID    WebServers
INSTANCE    i-INSTANCE_ID_1 ami-IMAGE_ID_1  ec2-external-ip-of-instance_1.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com   ip-internal-ip-of-instance_1.eu-west-1.compute.internal running KEY_PAIR_NAME   0   (nil)   m1.large    date_and_time_start_1   REGION  aki-KERNEL  (nil)   (nil)   monitoring-disabled some.internal.ip.1  some.external.ip.1  (nil)   (nil)   ebs (nil)   (nil)   (nil)   (nil)   paravirtual xen (nil)   sg-SECURITYGROUPID_1    default (nil)
BLOCKDEVICE /dev/sda1   vol-VOLUME_ID_1 date_and_time_vol_start_1   true
TAG instance    i-INSTANCE_ID_1 Name    webserver_name_1 
RESERVATION r-RESERVATION_ID_2  OWNER_ID    WebServers
INSTANCE    i-INSTANCE_ID_2 ami-IMAGE_ID_2  ec2-external-ip-of-instance_2.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com   ip-internal-ip-of-instance_2.eu-west-1.compute.internal running KEY_PAIR_NAME   0   (nil)   m1.large    date_and_time_start_2   REGION  aki-KERNEL  (nil)   (nil)   monitoring-disabled some.internal.ip.2  some.external.ip.2  (nil)   (nil)   ebs (nil)   (nil)   (nil)   (nil)   paravirtual xen (nil)   sg-SECURITYGROUPID_2    default (nil)
BLOCKDEVICE /dev/sda1   vol-VOLUME_ID_2 date_and_time_vol_start_2   true
TAG instance    i-INSTANCE_ID_2 Name    webserver_name_2
```

where the output for each instance is four lines, starting with RESERVATION, INSTANCE, BLOCKDEVICE and TAG.  As you may be able to see, the output above is for two instances,  webserver_name_1 and webserver_name_2.

I need to be able to obtain the following from that output:

- The second field from the second line (i-INSTANCE_ID_1)
- The third field from the third line (vol-VOLUME_ID_1)
- The fifth field from the fourth line (webserver_name_1)
- The second field from the sixth line (i-INSTANCE_ID_2)
- The third field from the seventh line (vol-VOLUME_ID_2)
- The fifth field from the eighth line (webserver_name_2)

and this command is to be issued against our ec2 fleet, so will need to continue as above with the tenth, eleventh, twelfth lines, then fourteenth, fifteenth, sixteenth etc etc

As the ec2-describe-instances command takes a long time to return output, I don't want to keep reiterating it to return output for each instance; I'd rather take the output from the single iteration and use that.

I've attempted to take various ways of retrieving this output but I am having difficulty stepping through each instances result.

Any help gratefully received (and any good pointers to awk tutorials also gratefully received) !!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your question, but think you may be looking for something like this:

```
someEC2command | awk '
/^INSTANCE/     {instance_id=$2}
/^BLOCKDEVICE/  {volid=$3}
/^TAG/          {tag=$5;print instance_id,volid,tag}'
```

which gives output:

```
i-INSTANCE_ID_1 vol-VOLUME_ID_1 webserver_name_1
i-INSTANCE_ID_2 vol-VOLUME_ID_2 webserver_name_2
```

So, when it sees lines starting "INSTANCE" it picks up field 2, when it sees lines starting "BLOCKDEVICE" it picks up volid from field3, and every time it sees lines starting "TAG" it picks up the tag and then prints whatever it has found so far.

As regards an *awk* tutorial/reference... youy only need one, see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf).

Comment: Thanks very much indeed Mark, that does exactly what I hoped to achieve.  I will read through that awk users guide, much appreciated!